# Reusable jQuery Function - Angular

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, jquery-plugins

I've a self-invoking jQuery function which adds re-sizing functionality to table columns
(source: https://codepen.io/jasongardner/pen/QNOXym)

Called from AfterViewInit Lifecycle

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(function () {
      var startX,startWidth,$handle,$table,pressed = false;
      //rest of functionality
 }
```

Since I need to use this across the application , is there a way to create colRisezable(https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable) plugin kind of Re-usable components for Angular Project?

Answer (score 0):

It's a function, you can have it in a separate shared file, and call it whenever you need.
Do you need to be more dynamic? You can create Angular [Attribute Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives), and add it to the tables that you need, you want it to be even better? Use [Renderedr2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) instead of jQuery, you don't need jQuery here you already have a great way provided by Angular